# how can I expot moset tree listing to JV Link directory?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, joomla1.5, joomla2.5

I were using moset tree in Joomla 1.5. And now I purchased JV Link directory for my Joomla 2.5 site. I want to export all my listings from moset tree (Joomla 1.5) to JV Link directory (Joomla 2.5). How can we export ?